# ASP.Net GridView doesn't refresh

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am relativity new to asp.net programming, so this one has me stumped. I manually created a dataset and set its value to the Datasource of the GridView control and then call the Databind method, but it isn't refreshing. I recreated a simple version of what I am doing so someone can advise me what I am doing wrong. I didn't include the Master file, as I didn't see it as pertainent.

**Code for ASP page**

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="TestGridView._Default" %>
```

## Updating price please stand by.

```
<p>
    <asp:GridView ID="GV1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="VendorNumber" HeaderText="Vendor" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PartNumber" HeaderText="Part or Sku" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Message" HeaderText="Error Message" />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</p>
<br />
<br />
<%
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Response.Write(Me.UpdatePricing())

    End If
%>
```

**Code for Code Behind**

```
Public Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Public Function UpdatePricing() As String
    Dim showerrors As Boolean = False

    Dim Head As New PnAHead()

    Dim ds As DataSet = Head.GetErrorDataset()

    If (ds.Tables("Errors").Rows.Count > 0) Then
        showerrors = True
    End If

    If showerrors Then
        GV1.DataSource = ds
        GV1.DataBind()
    End If

    Return "Sales Line Number has been updated."
End Function
```

End Class

**Class that creates the Dataset**

```
Public Class PnAHead

Public Function GetErrorDataset() As DataSet
    Dim dstemp = New DataSet()
    Dim tbl As DataTable = dstemp.Tables.Add("Errors")
    Dim col As DataColumn = tbl.Columns.Add("VendorNumber", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    col.MaxLength = 20

    col = tbl.Columns.Add("PartNumber", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    col.MaxLength = 50

    col = tbl.Columns.Add("Message", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    col.MaxLength = 500

    Dim row As DataRow

    row = tbl.NewRow()

    row("VendorNumber") = "Vendor 1"
    row("PartNumber") = "Part Number 1"
    row("Message") = "Message for Part 1"

    tbl.Rows.Add(row)

    row = tbl.NewRow()

    row("VendorNumber") = "Vendor 2"
    row("PartNumber") = "Part Number 2"
    row("Message") = "Message for Part 2"

    tbl.Rows.Add(row)

    Return dstemp
End Function
```

End Class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your call to update pricing into the Page_Load event. You can also remove the Response.Write().

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
      Me.UpdatePricing()
  End If
End Sub
```

You can do this in the .aspx page by wrapping the Page_Load event in script tags, like this:

```
<script type="text/VB" runat="server">

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        Me.UpdatePricing()
    End If
End Sub

</script>
```

Or you can just add the Page_Load event to your code behind, which i think is preferable as you already have a code behind page.

Comment: Thank you that was the solution. I come from the world of Windows programming and I could update a datagridview at any point and it always worked. Do you know why you have to call it form the Page_Load event to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you debug your code and check of the dataset has data or not,u can do this by adding a break point on the row where you set the data source,you can get into the properties of the dataset..and you will find a magnifier icon..click it,,a pop  up window will open showing the set of data retrieved.

Comment: I had already verified that the data was in the dataset as part of my troubleshooting. I just didn't understand why it wasn't refreshing.